# Can one use logarithms to solve the equations $2=3^x + x$ and $2=3^x x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Could someone explain how would you solve:

$$2=3^x + x$$

and

$$2=3^x \cdot x$$

I can only solve halfway through.

And why is

$$10^{\log (x)}= x$$

Thanks

Comment: Well, $\log = (\exp)^{-1}$ and $e^{\log(x)} = (\exp \circ \log)(x) = (\exp \circ (\exp)^{-1})(x) = Id(x) = x$. Or, $\log(x) = y$ such that $10^y = x$. Either way this is definitional.

Comment: Glibly: you wouldn't. You can approximate the solutions without too much difficulty, but there's no elementary solution.

Comment: The notation $\log x$ is ambiguous. In most elementary applications it is assumed to be of base $10$ while in analysis it denotes the natural logarithm of base $e$. Regardless, one should clarify what they mean by their notation if their is any chance of misinterpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a log is a quantity representing the power to which a fixed number (the base) must be raised to produce a given number.

Below is a simple example, 
\[ 10^{2}=100 \]
So
\[ \log_{10} 100=\log_{10} 10^{2}=2\log_{10} 10= 2 \]
And
\[
10^{\log_{10} 100}=10^{2} = 100
\]
Generally
\[
b^{\log_{b}(x)}=x
\]
Also, the solutions to both of those problems cannot be found using elementary functions.

To solve these equations, we must use the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). This function will provide the value of $x$ in equations that take the form $z=xe^{x}$. 
\[
z=xe^{x}\Longleftrightarrow W(z)=x
\]
Since you're curious, here are the solutions
\[ 2=3^{x}x=x3^{x}=xe^{\ln 3^{x}}=xe^{x\ln 3} \]
\[ 2\ln 3=(x\ln 3)e^{x\ln 3} \]
\[ W(2\ln 3) = x\ln 3 \]
\[ x = \frac{W(2\ln 3)}{\ln 3} \]
And after some trial and error, 
\[ 2=3^{x}+x \]
\[ 2-x=3^{x} \]
\[ (2-x)3^{2}=3^{x}3^{2} \]
\[ (2-x)\frac{3^{2}}{3^{x}}=9 \]
\[ 9=(2-x)\frac{3^{2}}{3^{x}}=(2-x)3^{2-x}=(2-x)e^{\ln 3^{2-x}}=(2-x)e^{(2-x)\ln 3} \]
\[ 9\ln 3=((2-x)\ln 3)e^{(2-x)\ln 3} \]
\[ W(9\ln 3)=(2-x)\ln 3 = 2\ln 3-x\ln 3 \]
\[ W(9\ln 3) - 2\ln 3= -x\ln 3 \]
\[ x=\frac{2\ln 3 - W(9\ln 3)}{\ln 3} \]

Comment: Thanks and could explain how would we go about solving without elementary functions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications

Comment: @Ozi Basically, if you were to use the Lambert W function to solve an equation, you would first rewrite it as $y e^y = a$ for some expressions $y$ and $a$. In this case we have $y=W(a)$, by the definition of $W$. It is not too hard to show that $W$ is uniquely defined for nonnegative real arguments (since $x e^x$ is an increasing function).

Answer (score 1):

The two first equations cannot be solved using elementary functions.

There are algebraic ways to explain the third equation, but here is an intuitive way:

What is the definition of $\log_{10} x$? It means: to what power do I have to raise $10$ to get $x$?
Imagine you raise $10$ to that particular power. What do you get? $x$!